# Can't import file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose I have

```
Directory\Folder1\File1.py\class Something, 
Directory\Folder2\File2.py
```

I want to import Something from File1 into File2
I encounter ModuleNotFoundError

I tried:

```
from Folder1.File1 import Something
```

What's happening:

```
The class imports and all the methods shows up but,
when I run the File2, It returns ModuleNotFoundError

EDIT: Unless the files are in the same folder the import doesn't work No Matter What I Try.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Can you add the code from the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the file "File1.py" exists in the specified path and make sure that the module you are trying to import (File1.py) is correctly defined and contains the necessary functions or classes.

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append("Directory\Folder1\File1.py")

import File1 as mains
```

Now you can use the file by calling the var mains.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the issue is the comes from the project organisation.
In python you can `from x import y` if your files are organised as packages (thus with an `__init__.py` file)

It seems you could do :

```py
# File2.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/Directory/Folder1')


from File1 import Something
```

Does this work ?

I would advice however to work under automatically managed projects, in IDE like PyCharm. It makes it more simple and safe.

Answer (score 0):

I see your import is `Folder.file1`; due to that they are at the same directory, you don't need the `Folder.` part, you can just include the `file1` like this:

Here's an example:

### file1:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def foo(self):
        print("Hello, World!")
```

### file2:

```
from file1 import Something # As you can see no need for the directory.

something = Something()
something.foo()
```

I run it at console:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\****>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\****'; & ...\file2.py' 
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Brother I have tried everything. Nothing works

Comment: Can you add the code and the error message please?